# Pick email address from .To

Tags: vba, outlook

My code will take the email address from the `.To` property, and send another email.

When the address is autocompleted, it has John Smith instead of john.smith@email.dot. The `.To` is empty for VBA code.

Is it possible to bypass it?

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objNewMail1 As Outlook.MailItem    
Dim strTo As String

strTo = objMail.To

Set objNewMail1 = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objNewMail1
    .To = strTo
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: What is „whisper“ and what kind of shape are you talking about? Might a screenshot explain it?

Comment: "whisper" is function when you use mail adress once or you have adress already in contact list. So you dont type email but few letters and outlook pick rest of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties - they, generally, include only the display names, not email addresses.

Loop through all recipients in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and use the `Recipient.Address` property - keep in mind you might have an EX type address, nit SMTP in case of Exchange, you might have to use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` (`GetExchangeUser` will return null for the non-Exchange address entries).

The recipient kind (`olTo` / `olCC` / `olBCC`) is stored in the `Recipient.Type` property.

```
   dim recip, newRecip
   ...
   With objNewMail1
        for each recip in objMail.Recipients
          set newRecip = .Recipients.Add(recip.Address)
          newRecip.Type = recip.Type 
        next
        .Send
    End With
```

Comment: thank you for answer, can you pls add you type of code to mine ? im lost.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Looping through recipients? Accessing the Address and Type properties? Or something else?

Comment: problem is how to everything put to my code, how declare MailItem.Recipients with Recipients.Adress and how use olTo.

Comment: declare Dim recip As Outlook.MailItem ?

Comment: it doesnt work, object .To is blank and saved as draft

Comment: Outlook.Recipient. What does not work? Are you getting an error?